# Unpack and copy ear to a local directory

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, ear

I need to unpack an ear archive and copy it to a local directory using maven, is there a maven plugin to do this? I have used maven upload plugin to copy the file, but unable to unpack it. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maven ear plugin ?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

I guess this explodes the ear content to a target directory. Please go through the examples

Or
maven dependency plugin can also help.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I have gone through the example [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/unpacking-a-module.html) but I cannot understand how to give the target directory, could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>A</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ear</artifactId>
                    <version>version</version>
                    <type>ear</type>
                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/ear</outputDirectory>
                    <excludes>**/*.jar</excludes>

                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>`